# Display Django DateTime Field with strftime() method

Tags: python, django

I am trying to format the string of a DateTimeField contained in one of my models.

I am using this method inside the model:

```
def HTMLDisplayTime(self):
        time = self.time.date.strftime(%a %H:%M  %d/%m/%y)
        return time
```

Where "self.time" refers to the DateTimeField in question.

I have tried several variations, omitting some items, with and without `.date` preceding the `.strftime` method, and have imported both `import datetime` and `from datetime import datetime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using quotes around the format argument in strftime() like:

```
time = self.time.strftime('%a %H:%M  %d/%m/%y')
```